# Deleting selected template

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new at javascript and jQuery. I am making a template of addresses and image of map and i have a delete button. How do i make the delete button work using jquery?

```
    function onDeleteAddress(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    };

    function renderAddresses(addressArr){
        for (let index = 0; index < addressArr.length; index++) {
            const template = getTemplate();

            var mapUrl = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${addressArr[index].lineOne}, ${addressArr[index].lineTwo}, ${addressArr[index].city}, ${addressArr[index].state}, ${addressArr[index].zipCode}&zoom=14&size=200x200&markers=color:red|${addressArr[index].lineOne}, ${addressArr[index].lineTwo}, ${addressArr[index].city}, ${addressArr[index].state}, ${addressArr[index].zipCode}&key=AIzaSyCQHurErpXDh3Y89jvtzzv_O_3tYyoeptI`;

            template.find('.card-name').text(addressArr[index].name);
            template.find('.line-one').text(addressArr[index].lineOne);
            template.find('.line-two').text(addressArr[index].lineTwo);
            template.find('.city-name').text(addressArr[index].city);
            template.find('.state-name').text(addressArr[index].state);
            template.find('.zip-code').text(addressArr[index].zipCode);
            template.find('.country').text(addressArr[index].country);
            template.find('img').attr('src', mapUrl);

            $('.clone-container').append(template);


        }
    };

    function emptyAllAddresses(){
        $('.clone-container').empty();
    };

    function onDeleteAddress(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    };
```

i want the template to be deleted when they press delete. i get this error.

"The onDeleteAddress function > Should delete the template selected"
"Expected 5 to be 4, 'The clone container should have 4 children once onDeleteAddress is called'."

Comment: Can you check addressArr.length , whether it should be addressArr.length-1?

Comment: @dev it didn't work :(

Comment: When you press delete button, you have to pass selector from Delete button click event. And get it in `onDeleteAddress()` function argument like `onDeleteAddress($selector)` then instead of `$(this).parent().remove();` , you have to put `$selector.parent().remove();`